# Can a PC realistically dual-wield two Glock 17s?

Tags: weapons, gurps, zombies

In my *GURPS Lite* zombie apocalypse campaign one of my players wanted his PC to wield two Glock 17s. I thought it would be cool, but I’m not sure it’d be realistic. Is there a realistic way to dual-wield twin pistols?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it appears to be a real-world research question about practicalities of real-world firearm wielding, which is outside our purview. Whilst we can answer questions about rules, it's almost always not our domain to evaluate how those rules or in-game possibilities line up with reality. See [our campaign research question guidance](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1609/1204).

Comment: Assuming that closure may be incorrect: Could you do me a favour and confirm whether you're asking about the rules or performing real-world research?

Comment: I'm going to switch the hold reason to "unclear" just to make the hold, um, *clearer*. :) If it turns out that it's about real-world realism it can stay closed (and maybe we can suggest somewhere it'd be on topic), but if the clarification is that it's about what's possible in GURPS then we can take that hold off and remove the off-topic answers to give it a fresh start.

Comment: (If it is about what GURPS has to say about dual pistols, could you also clarify which edition you're using? Thanks!)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If you haven't already, please confirm with the edit history that my edit didn't accidentally change the question's intent.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, I see. I see the original was specific about realism “in real life”. In that case it's likely to stay closed — but if they decide “in GURPS” is interesting to edit it into, I think that'd be fine.

Comment: Yep, definitely 100% off topic then under the original revision but "how would this work in gurps, if at all" would be fine if LightningColin would be interested in that..

Comment: GURPS 4e has a clear answer about doing this in realistic campaigns, and I'll happily provide it if the question is re-opened.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make it as realistic as possible. I’ll delete it.

Comment: Never mined I guess it will just be closed. We’re using 3e, forgot that in the question.

Comment: It's *not* that the *system* is preventing the site from answering—I mean, seriously, I ran a *GURPS 3e* campaign for a decade; *I* can answer questions about that edition, if need be—, but that the question as it stands is about *real-world shooting* rather than *GURPS.* If you want a rules-based answer, please, rephrase the question to get one! Something like *Without using cinematic advantages or maneuvers, how can a human PC make attacks with two automatic pistols simultaneously?* or something.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not entirely sure that this is an RPG-based question, because it seems more like you are asking, "*Is it possible to fire two Glock 17s at once?*" instead of a question specifically about GURPS, I will give you an answer.

As someone who has personally shot Glock 17s before, you can most certainly shoot two at once. However, you can't aim the same way you can when you're firing one at a time, you will suffer from hand fatigue faster than when you're shooting in a proper stance since all the recoil is being absorbed by one hand, your aim will be less steady, the follow-through will be more difficult, and you won't be nearly as precise as when you are only shooting one.

When you shoot a single weapon with both hands, you do two things that you do not do when you fire a gun with one hand:

1. You absorb the force of recoil across a roughly-triangular area comprised of both your arms and the space between.
2. Your arms counteract the random movements of each other, meaning that the barrel sways less.

You can also aim down the sights when you shoot with both hands; you cannot aim down two separate gun's sights at once simply due to how the human brain works. Thus, when you shoot from the hip with any weapon, you rely much more on estimating the natural point of aim accurately to hit the target than you do when you can rely on both the natural point of aim and the calibrated sight system.

Red-Dots on the end of the guns can show you where each gun is pointing to make this easier, but it doesn't protect you from hand fatigue or unsteadiness.

Comment: Hi SeraphsWrath. Due to our stance that [real-world research unrelated to RPG expertise is off topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1609/1204), questions are almost always not looking for real-world research -- and, if that is all an answer consists of, it indicates the question is probably off topic. Instead, questions like this are *generally* asking about guidance with the rules, and real-world information is only relevant insofar as it can be related back to the mechanics of the games we play (because the mechanics may or may not agree).

Comment: I say "generally" since the question has been closed, on account of if it is doing real-world research, it is off topic. However, if it *is not* doing real-world research, but asking about game rules, this answer would be Not An Answer due to not providing information about the game rules. Hence the reason I'm leaving this comment to let you know: you can see the catch 22 that either way things work out, answers of this nature must in turn be drawn back to guidance in the game themselves or wind up as being a sort of answer we're not looking to gather here.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, He could wield two Glocks.**

They are just handguns and I have seen a couple of people on the range handle two weapons at one time.  The question I think you are really asking is about switching out magazines.  Most automatic handguns like the Glock (I am more familiar with the Barretta 92F) has a single button that will release the magazine catch and the magazine will just fall out of the gun stock by gravity.

The size of the characters hands will determine if he needs to remove the second gun from his hand to enable him to replace the magazine.  A person with big hands or long fingers should have little problem replacing a magazine with the hand holding the second gun.  Of course this is supposing he has easy access to the replacement magazine.  And nothing jostling him.

Tucking the second gun under an arm as seen in many movies should do the trick too.  Of course this is where the DM can have fun making sure the gun stays there as he dodges all those incoming zombie attacks.

In real life accuracy would surely suffer.  It is very difficult to concentrate/aim at multiple targets.  In the old west many had two weapons, but few used them together.  It was more for having another weapon ready to grab so you didn't have to reload.  Using a Glock that is less of a problem because of how quick a magazine can be dropped and replaced.

Most that I have seen using two weapons either alternated between the two or just shot as fast as possible to get the lead downrange.  So that is the real life.  Game life is different, thank goodness.